# Output not as expected in fwrite

Tags: c, file, fwrite

I am learning fread and fwrite of c and made a basic code to write a structure using fwrite in a file . Output was there on the

```
       #include<stdio.h>
       int main()
       {
       FILE *f;
       int i,q=0;
       typedef struct {
                       int a;
                       char ab[10];
       }b;
       b var[2];
       f=fopen("new.c","w");
       printf("Enter values in structure\n");
       for(i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
       {
           scanf("%d",&var[i].a);
           scanf("%s",var[i].ab);
       }
       fwrite(var,sizeof(var),1,f);

       fclose(f);
       return 0;
       }
```

The output was not smooth as it contained weird characters inside the file. I opened the file in binary mode too but in vain. Is this some kind of buffer problem?

Comment: The arguments of fwrite may need adjusting.  You have "1" for the 3rd argument telling it that you only want to output 1 element.  And for the 2nd argument, you want element size, which should be byte.  (int and char are two different sizes of coarse, so the common denominator is byte sized output).  Try `fwrite(var, 1, sizeof(var), f);`

Comment: @ryykker, OP's code is fine.

Comment: @CarlNorum - agreed, I went away, worked it out, using fprintf (as you suggested) and it works fine.  Thanks.  May I ask what tool are you using to get the File Offset, Data and Relationship columns?

Comment: @ryyker - I made it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weird" characters inside your file are probably the bytes of the binary integers you're writing out.  `fwrite` is writing the bits of `var` directly to the file, not converting that into a human readable format.  If you want that, use `fprintf` instead.

Here's an example directly from your code above:

```
$ ./example 
Enter values in structure
5 hello
8 world
$ hexdump -vC new.c 
00000000  05 00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c  6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....hello.......|
00000010  08 00 00 00 77 6f 72 6c  64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....world.......|
00000020
```

Notice that the first four bytes at offset `0x00` and `0x10` are the numbers entered (little-endian and 32-bit because of my machine), followed by the strings entered, plus a bit of structure padding.  All broken down:

```
 File Offset     Data (ASCII)     Relationship to source
     0             05               var[0].a  7:0
     1             00               var[0].a 15:8
     2             00               var[0].a 23:16
     3             00               var[0].a 31:24
     4             68 (h)           var[0].ab[0]
     5             65 (e)           var[0].ab[1]             
     6             6c (l)           var[0].ab[2]
     7             6c (l)           var[0].ab[3]
     8             6f (o)           var[0].ab[4]
     9             00 (NUL)         var[0].ab[5]
    10             00 (NUL)         var[0].ab[6]
    11             00 (NUL)         var[0].ab[7]
    12             00 (NUL)         var[0].ab[8]
    13             00 (NUL)         var[0].ab[9]
    14             00               structure padding
    15             00               structure padding
    16             08               var[1].a  7:0
    17             00               var[1].a 15:8
    18             00               var[1].a 23:16
    19             00               var[1].a 31:24
    20             77 (w)           var[1].ab[0]
    21             6f (o)           var[1].ab[1]             
    22             72 (r)           var[1].ab[2]
    23             6c (l)           var[1].ab[3]
    24             64 (d)           var[1].ab[4]
    25             00 (NUL)         var[1].ab[5]
    26             00 (NUL)         var[1].ab[6]
    27             00 (NUL)         var[1].ab[7]
    28             00 (NUL)         var[1].ab[8]
    29             00 (NUL)         var[1].ab[9]
    30             00               structure padding
    31             00               structure padding
```

Comment: so integers are not readable but then strings are readable ,why? and is this just a case with integers then why fwrite is used to print structures?

Comment: Because a string is already in a human-readable format.  An integer isn't - it's just a number.  What else would you expect?  You're using `scanf` even... I think you need to go back to basics on how computers store data.

Comment: "Because a string is already in a human-readable format. An integer isn't - it's just a number. What else would you expect? you are using scanf even" ...So a number while printing inside a block(that is structure)that is mixed with string ( or character) to a file will not be in a readable form because ??.. please explain i am at basics.

Comment: is this because strings are null terminated and understood in readable format but integers aren't null terminated and also there is structure padding which also makes it unreadable after mixing with integer bits ?

Comment: Well the null terminator is there, certainly, but that doesn't have anything to do with the integers.  What are you trying to ask?

Comment: i just asked why integer is not readable(whats the use of fwrite if it can;t print an integer perfectly).. you said its some storage related thing . Can you explain a little

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a binary file and a text file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38115/discussion-between-mrigendra-and-carl-norum)